# botocore - Tags are missing from 'describe_images' response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, botocore

When I do something like:

`ec2_client.describe_images(ImageIds=['ami-123456'])`

The response I get is missing the 'Tags'. This is not the case when I do the same call using aws cli:

`aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-123456`

Comment: The docs mention a `Tags` field in response: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images

Comment: Yes I know. This is why I raised the issue because I do not get the `Tags` field.

Comment: Show how you're trying to get the tags?

Comment: The `Tags` are simply not there. If I do `response = ec2_client.describe_images(ImageIds=['ami-123456'])` and then print the response, I see the rest of the fields but not the `Tags`

Comment: `response` is a list of `images`. Each `image` will have different `Tags`.

Comment: Well... As you can see from my example, I get info from just one image. Anyway, the thing is that tags are not there. The same call using aws cli gives me the Tags.

Comment: Does the ami you're fetching has tags attached? I tested it for one of mine and the Tags field is missing in all SDK (and CLI) responses if there are none.

Comment: What is the output of `boto3.client('ec2').describe_images(ImageIds=['ami-123456'])['Images'][0]['Tags']` ?

Comment: @helloV Yes. `response['Images'][0]` returns the relevant info for my ami but `response['Images'][0]['Tags'‌​]` returns `keyerror` (as expected since there is no `Tags` field

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes. I can see my tags in AWS web interface. As I said I get the tags when I use aws cli. It's botocore that is not returning them.

Comment: @GeorgeB. This is from aws-cli: https://www.hastebin.com/yidarezoji

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The problem is caused by the fact that credentials from another account was used due to our setup with parent and child accounts